# Buying a Windows 7 product key

Tags: windows, installation, oem

I have installed Windows 7 more times than I can count.  Most of the time I have either had an OEM disk or downloaded from digitalriver and had a product key laying around or on the back of the PC I was servicing.

I just got to thinking what if one doesn't have the OEM disc and can not read the product key on the back of the PC.  How would one go about obtaining a legitimate key after downloading installing from the official digitalriver iso.  Does the "Activate Windows" screen allow you to purchase a product key with a credit card?

Answer (score 3):

If there is still a working previous windows install, you can use several utilities to recover the key.

If there is none, you either:

- Check your documentation for the key.
- Or restore a previous backup and recover the key.
- Or purchase a new key (E.g. via [Microsofts own webshop](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/ThemeID.27509700/Windows-7-Ultimate/productID.216647200)).
- Or install a different OS (and optionally: curse).

Comment: Digitalrivercontent is not a legal MS reseller.  It is a website, by Microsoft, that allows you to download the ISOs.  Of course the ISOs alone are worthless if you want a legal copy of Windows.  I was wondering where one could just buy keys online.  I've never been in this situation.  Check out all the direct links to the isos http://itsolution.forumslog.com/t20-download-all-windows-7-selections-iso-image

Comment: I stand corrected. D.R. hosts the files for MS. It does not sell them. I ill add the link to the microsoftstore.

Comment: Is there an updated link to purchase a Windows 7 key?